# How to check if code is being executed inside eval()?

Tags: php, eval

How to check, if a line of code, that is actually being executed runs from inside of [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function? Did anyone have to deal with something like this?

Comment: You could override the default `eval` function, see docs here http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Comment: `var_dump()` works perfectly fine in `eval()`. Problem is that I have to distinguish, if a library is being executed from inside an `eval()` while running. I've tried the global variable solution, but inside `eval()` you've got an access to the same variables as from outside.

Comment: worse case: looking through the  the stack trace to see where the eval was called from? xdebug has some useful functions for this - I was using them just the other day. You have xdebug active?

Comment: XDebug is not an option. But I didn't consider the stack trace, seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for your input! With your help I found the solution (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to thank [Ryan Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400252/how-to-check-if-code-is-being-executed-inside-eval?noredirect=1#comment64234586_38400252) for his advice!

`function is_eval()
{
    $debug = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
    foreach ($debug as $step => $trace) {
        // ignore class calls
        if (isset($trace['class'])) {
            continue;
        }
        if (isset($trace['function']) && 'eval' === $trace['function']) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: How does it work? When should I call is_eval function? It's not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your eval function.

debug_to_console( "Code ran" );